# scrollRowToVisible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The error goes out when scrollRowToVisible is executed. 'UITableView'  ..in Xcode.. May not respond to '- scrollRowToVisible'

It writes as follows. 
IBOutlet UITableView *tableViews;
[tableViews scrollRowToVisible:2];
I want to move it to the second line.

ReloadData operates.

Why

Answer (score 1):

`reloadData` is a valid method on `UITableView`. `scrollRowToVisible:` is not, and I have no idea where you got it—there's nothing else called that in the API. The method you're looking for is `-scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`, which you'd use like this:

```
[tableViews scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

`scrollRowToVisible:` is for using in desktop Mac applications, with an `NSTableView`. If you're programming for iPhone, use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` instead.